# Print when expression ireport more than one condition

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Can i put more than one condition at print when expression? and can pls tell the syntax. 
example,

(cb.flag = 'A' or cb.flag = 'B' or cb.flag = 'C') and cb.type <> 'O'

- i need to use OR condition together with AND.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax is `(condition) ? value1 : value2` In place of value1 and value2 you may have other constraints.

Here is an example that uses a Java constraint:

```
(($F{ca} > 8) && ($F{ca} < 12) ? "near 10" : (($F{name}.charAt(0) == 'A') ? "A": "Not A" ))
```

These are Java expressions, so you have to be careful with `==` and `=`.

Now the print part...

So far you have defined a Variable `variable1`, which is a String variable (could be anything else) and behaves accordingly to the constraint you have defined.

You just need to drag it from your the Variables group of your Report Inspector to the zone (most likely the Detail zone) of your report. Then it becomes `$V{variable1}` and prints in your zone whatever the constrain dictates. That's it.

[image]

Comment: the syntax is correct, but i want to put it in "print when expression". Didnt it suppose to be true false statement? this equation is more on selection right?

Comment: Avialis : anyway, thanks. Your answer help me to gain my logic. I just try to do (($F{flag}.equals('A'))||($F{flag}.equals('B'))||($F{flag}.equals('C')))&&(!F${type}).equals('O')  but i just wonder if the (!$F{type}).equals is the right syntax for NOT EQUALS TO.

Comment: @Chi: great! I have just added a few words about the steps you will need to do for getting the value to the printer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use - `( $F{sex}.equals("0") ? "Male" : "Female")`